# Algorithm that will read through standard mathematical function to plot a graph. (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem with my program to create a Mathematical Students book, I am trying to create one part with a graph that will draw mathematical functions, that you will insert.

But I am struggling with how to analyze what function was entered. So basically I have a text box, where you write something and then press a button. The algorithm should analyze what youve typed in the text box and then gather data to run for-cycle to plot a graph.
I am thinking of tons of if functions that will always check what is in the Text Box. Like this:

```
this->chart1->Series["Funkce 1"]->Points->Clear();

            if(this->funkce1->Text == L"x")
            {

                    for(int i = -100; i <= 100; i++)
                    {
                        this->chart1->Series["Funkce 1"]->Points->AddXY((i) , (i));
                    }
            }

            if(this->funkce1->Text == L"x^2")
                {
                    for(int i = -100; i <= 100; i++)
                    {
                        this->chart1->Series["Funkce 1"]->Points->AddXY((i) , (i*i));
                    }
                }
```

And continuing this way for loads and loads of possibilities that you can write.
I must admit it is not an efficient way but right now the only one I can think of. By the way at begging you have to clear the data after previous graph points.

What would be a better way to analyze the entered function?

Comment: Maybe you could start from mapping your "TextBox" to a Array base polynomial representation", for ex: 
I you have the function y = x^3+x+-7
That would be represented in something like A = [-7, 1,0,1] and that is the same as Y = A[0] + A[1]*x + A[2]*x^2 + A[3]*x^3 , that would be easly evaluated and I think is pretty, but using this method you can't do things like Y = x^x couse it only works for polynomial functions.

you could also use http://www.gnuplot.info/

Comment: The Boost library has some support for writing parsers (in particular Boost Spirit). There are also loads of different parser generators around. However, since this is a common problem, chances are that you can find a library that directly does what you want. Voted to close as a "recommendations, please" question.